# Most simple way to create maven repository at server

Tags: java, maven, repository

I have problem- I'v got some java code at my computer in 3 or 4 projects. This code is used in a lot of places in other projects.Not i'm using this cod that- I'm adding to dependencies groupId, artifactId and version, then add manually in inteliji idea place with this files pom. In future it will be used by more people than me, so i need to share this files(on my physical server).So i need send it to server but not as a jar only as a java code.I need same effect as in for example in Junit. I add dependencies, and i can use TestCase class . How can I made it in easiest way ???

Comment: If you write „_So i need send it to server but not as a jar only as a java code._“ are you looking for [Source Code Management (SCM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control)? If yes, this has nothing to do with Maven (directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share jars that you have build, you can set up a Nexus or Artifactory server and deploy them there.

Other people can use these repositories to download the artifacts.

Comment: i always thought of jar as an  executable  file, i don't know its archive, so i need nexus, thx i know all :D